# Merge C and D drive, keep Windows on D

Tags: windows, partitioning, drive-letter

I have a PC with a harddrive that has two partitions, C: containing an old beta version of Windows 8 and D: containing Windows 7.

I would like to remove Windows 8, and merge the two partitions into one. The merging process itself will probably be doable, but I'm afraid that Windows will then name that partition C: which will obviously break all kind of thing that still refer D: (registry, shortcuts, ...)

Is it possible to merge partitions, and have Windows keep D: as driver letter for the first partition, or will the first partition always be C:?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable. Driveletters are not changed unless you do it yourself or you remove/create a partition.

So what you would want to do is move all data from the C drive to the D drive (or an external backup if its too much data) and prepare to remove the C partition entirely, then use software such as Partition Magic to resize the D partition.

By using this method, the D letter will remain the same. If you want to be totally safe, first remove the C partition and leave the unpartitioned space in tact, then reboot to see if you can still access windows. If not, boot back into partition magic and recreate the partition.

You can create a really small partition, or resize the C partition to really small, and not give it a drive letter, and then resize the D partition to really large if you want to.

Comment: OK, that looks good. I always thought that Windows used some hard coded sequence starting at C, but now I couldn't find any reference to it. Do you have any idea where Windows stores drive letter information? (Yeah, I know, this should really be a new question ;-)

Comment: Windows doesn't, the harddisk does in the master boot record. Windows bootloader boots to harddiskx/partitionx regardless of the driveletter, but once in windows, the installed programs refer to the driveletter.